# Load a vector drawable into imageview from sd card

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-vectordrawable

I want to show a vector image (say vectorimage.xml) in an imageview from the sd card. Please throw some insight on how to do this in android. 
What I have tried already :-

```
String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ folder/productImage.xml";

bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
Drawable bgrImageDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapImage);
```

The above code snippet does not work since the bitmapImage is coming as null.

Comment: Are you getting path in imagepath check it and also check for permission in menifest

Comment: Yes,i have made this work with jpeg with same code snippet.

Comment: @RamyaBA Even I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Anyone found solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The BitmapFactory can't load vector drawables.
You have to use the VectorDrawable or VectorDrawableCompat class.
To load a vector drawable you need to use a xml loader.

Some parser like the one for the resources need a precompiled binary xml file. You can find them in the apk file when you put the vector drawable in the drawable resource directory.

Here is a sample to load it from the assets, you should be able to use a similar code for the loading from the sd card.

```
final XmlResourceParser parser = context.getAssets().openXmlResourceParser("assets/folder/image.xml");
drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXml(context.getResources(), parser);
```

This way needs at least Android 5.0

Comment: This isn´t twork for the Sd card (external storage).!

Comment: Created a request for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62435069

Comment: I don't see any way to load vector images outside App, @Rocket any idea?