# How to load an SVG file from SD Card into an ImageView?

Tags: android, svg, picasso

I'm trying to load an svg file downloaded into sd card with Picasso but it doesn't work.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath()+"/secciones.svg");
Picasso.with(context).load(file).into(holder.ivIcon);
```

I found this question before but he load the file from assets.
[Load a vector drawable into imageview from sd card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582698/load-a-vector-drawable-into-imageview-from-sd-card)

Is it possible to load the .svg downloaded into the imageView?

Comment: First, `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` has nothing to do with [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on most Android devices. Second, I do not think that Picasso supports SVG.

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve this by converting SVG to drawable before setting it to `ImageView`. For this purpose there is a nice library (a bit old and un-managed) [Here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/svg-android/wikis/Tutorial.wiki), however I tried and worked for me. The code is as below :

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File yourFile = new File(dir, "your_file_path/filename.svg");
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(yourFile);
        SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromInputStream(fileInputStream);
        Drawable drawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
        imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use SVG with android application. (yes…there are 3rd party libraries that we can use to work with SVG files)

Source : [Android — Working with VectorDrawable](https://medium.com/@nandankaushik/android-working-with-vectordrawable-can-we-easily-convert-svg-to-vectordrawable-e4000143b13f#.1esgc481p)

VectorDrawable images are simply xml file that contains all information of an image (like lines, curves etc. ) and the color associated with each one of them. The biggest advantage of using vectorDrawable is that we need only one image for different screen devices.This not only reduces the size of the final apk, also it simplifies the maintenance of the project.