# Download .svg or .xml to internal memory and show it in ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, fileinputstream, android-vectordrawable

I need to download vector images from server and display them in ImageViews. I succesfully downloaded the images to external storage, but now I'm having a problem displaying them.
I'm using a SVG library from larvalabs and here's the code:

```
File image = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.svg");
    if (image.exists()) {
        try {
            InputStream imageStream = new FileInputStream(image);
            SVGBuilder builder = new SVGBuilder();
            builder.readFromInputStream(imageStream);
            SVG svg = builder.build();
            Drawable draw = svg.getDrawable();
            ((ImageButton) view).setImageDrawable(draw);
            imageStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {...
```

It turns out that the InputStream is empty. But the file is there, the path shows to the correct directory, the file is as it should be, so I don't know what else could be the problem. I'm adding a print screen from debugger if it helps.
[Debugger Print Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axic3.png)

Comment: Looks like svg-android is no longer maintained, maybe switch to another SVG library

Comment: Can you include your entire stack trace?

Comment: Similar question was asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582698/load-a-vector-drawable-into-imageview-from-sd-card